# How to get acknowledgement after producing to kafka sink i.e. using FlinkKafkaProducer09

Tags: apache-flink

```
stream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer09<String>("Topic-name", new SimpleStringSchema(), 
properties));
```

Is there any callback or on completion for FlinkkafkaProducer?

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify your use-case in more details?

Answer (score 1):

You can try sending a message to the producer.

And once you send the message, you can write a callback on it. Thought it is an expensive operation, you should generally try to avoid it.

> The send() method is asynchronous. When called it adds the record to a
>   buffer of pending record sends and immediately returns. This allows
>   the producer to batch together individual records for efficiency.

You can look at its usage:

```
 ProducerRecord<byte[],byte[]> record = new ProducerRecord<byte[],byte[]>("the-topic", key, value);
producer.send(myRecord,
           new Callback() {
               public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
                   if(e != null)
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   System.out.println("The offset of the record we just sent is: " + metadata.offset());
               }
           });
```

Refer the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#send(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord,%20org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback)) for more details.